# Replacing values in html

Tags: java, android, jsoup

So I'm parsing a website using jsoup and then displaying the html in a text view.

It has some broken links so I have to go in and replace them. Here is some of my code:

```
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                              try {
            Elements links = doc.select("a");
                     for (Element i: links){
                           String relHref = i.attr("abs:href");
                           if (!relHref.startsWith("http://") && !relHref.startsWith("https://")){
                                      html = html.replace(relHref, "http://www.bths.edu"+ relHref);
                                      }
                          }
     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
            article.setText(Html.fromHtml(set));
            article.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
                                        }
                                    });
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting this error:

```
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
            at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.<init>(AbstractStringBuilder.java:82)
            at java.lang.StringBuilder.<init>(StringBuilder.java:67)
            at java.lang.String.replace(String.java:1374)
            at com.tod.android.bths.ArticleViewer$2.run(ArticleViewer.java:78)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Line 78 is

```
 html = html.replace(relHref, "http://www.bths.edu"+ relHref);
```

I do not get an error when i make this switch

```
String relHref = i.attr("href");
```

It's not what I need though... Why is it that abs:href gives me problems???

@Harald

```
  //So I've done this and now, I don't get an error. But nothing gets replaced. Why?

 if (!relHref.startsWith("http://") && !relHref.startsWith("https://")&& relHref!="" ){
 html = html.replace(relHref, "http://www.bths.edu"+ relHref);
                                    }
```

Comment: Increase the jvm heap and try the profiler to see where the usage is high.

Comment: Where does the error occur? Can you post a stack trace? `abs:` uses `org.jsoup.nodes.Node.absUrl(String)`. Does the `OutOfMemoryException` occur there?

Comment: Don't compare String with !=. Here you should use relHref.length()>0 .

Comment: @Harald I switched it but still, nothing gets replaced :(

Comment: And you have checked that relHref is a string once in a while that indeed appears in html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether `relHref` is the empty string, because if it is, every empty string in `html` will be replaced by a nonempty string. and there are tons of them.